# Sending email from local user account

Tags: java, android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I saw a lot of posts about this, but i am still confused.

I am using Javax mail for sending email without intent.

Is there a way to send email from local user address without asking for user credentials?

I know how to get user name of local user, but is it mandatory to use the user password?

something like Gmail Auth? can it help?

Comment: "local user address" has nothing do with with username/password. It all depends on the mail server you're connecting to. It's THAT server that's requiring credentials.

Comment: I am using Gmail - SMTP port 465 and i need the credentials of the device user

Comment: so you want to use the user's google account? you'd be better off invoking the built-in mail app instead.

Comment: The thing is i want to invoke an email without user intervention or UI and without asking for the user credntials.

Comment: an app that sends email on my behalf, using my identity, and tries to hide that fact from me, is an app I'd never install in the first place.

Comment: So you want to send an email from the user's email account without getting the username/password or any sort of auth token? Goodluck with that. Moreover, As a user I would be scared to install an app which can send email from my account without my intervention.

Comment: Think of the business a user want to scaduale a mail message from his box to address x with message y in 30 minutes from now. I just wanted to know if it is possible to send with his credentials without forcing him to provide them explicitly. If its not possible then i have no choice

Comment: You can use oauth for this, see https://github.com/telepuzinator/GmailSender and https://github.com/wareninja/generic-oauth2-login-for-android for examples.

Answer (score 0):

The password is required by the gmail server, and for good reason.  You would not want everyone being able to use your email account to send email without you being able to stop them.

The only way you will be able to accomplish what you want is to ask the user for their email password and store it so that you can use it later in automated sending.  When the user changes their gmail password you will need prompt them to update their credentials.